# Why are Hindu marriages done “Agni Sakshi” (fire as witness)

Tags: marriage, agni

While marrying, the hindus pledge considering "fire" as a witness. Is there any specific with fire that it is given priority over the other master elements of the universe?

Comment: Fire is Agni deva, he is the one who carries our ahuti (rice,ghee) to gods during homa, like a messenger between bhu-loka and deva-loka. Since marriage is a sacred vow taken by man & woman, it has to be done with sacred witness

Comment: But still that does not suffices the reason for fire to be the witness. Please do not get me wrong but I asked this question so that if there is a related reference mentioned in Vedas etc. could be highlighted here

Comment: I guess I found my answer here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16585/what-is-the-significance-of-fire-in-rituals