# Is Agni and Vayu great because RigVeda eulogized them or are they not great because they're subject to ego in Kenopanishad?

Tags: brahman, agni, kena-upanishad, vayu

The opening hymn of Rig Veda is for Agni , the god of fire I am assuming .
And then there are many more hymns , but then there're ones for Vayu, Mitra, Indra, and so on for the other deities.

The verses indicate Agni is grand and divine.

However , we see in the Kenopanishad, after having a victory over the demons, the gods rejoiced in ego and the Brahman assumed a Yaksha form to break their ego .

> Brahman, according to the story, obtained a victory for the gods; and
> by that victory of Brahman the gods became elated. They said to
> themselves: "Verily, this victory is ours; verily, this glory is ours
> only."
>
> Brahman, to be sure, understood it all and appeared before them. But
> they did not know who that adorable Spirit was. 3—6 They said to Agni
> (Fire): "O Agni! Find out who this great Spirit is." "Yes," he said
> and hastened to It. Brahman asked him: "Who are you?" He replied: "I
> am known as Agni; I am also called Jataveda."
>
> Brahman said: "What
> power is in you, who are so well known?" Fire replied: "I can burn
> all— whatever there is on earth." Brahman put a straw before him and
> said: "Burn this." He rushed toward it with all his ardour but could
> not burn it. Then he returned from the Spirit and said to the gods: "I
> could not find out who this Spirit is,"
> (from Chapter 3 of Kenopanishad)

Thus, we can see Agni who was very egoistic about power to burn all earth is unable to reduce a single piece of straw .
Next to be humbled is Vayu who couldn't blow away the same straw.

Indra is made of this realization. Note that indra doesn't see or question the yaksha which is a hidden metaphor of the fact that senses (indriya) can't see the lord.

So , the question is Is Agni and Vayu great because they're eulogized in mandala 1 of Rigveda or are they not so great because they are subject to ego and got their egos broken down by supreme deity.

PS : On a humorous note, one can add I may not be sitting and typing this if it were not for agni (temperature) in my body. :P

Comment: You also would not be writing this question without Vayu in you :P The Vedas glorify almost all of the devas whom we consider today as subordinates of the lord. That does not in any way deprive them of ego or any other such qualities because ultimately the Vedas praise each of these gods more like manifestations of the divine rather than established individual divinities.

Comment: all vedic gods are higher

Comment: Subjected to ego is not enough argument not to consider one great. Agni and Vayu are great deities, that Upanishad verse is preaching at the absolute level that nothing is higher than Brahman. Refer Katha Upanishad 2.2.15

Comment: When you say **Brahman** , do you mean Brahma or the Supreme God Brahman?

Comment: Vayu and Agni are great primarily because we can't really live without them..

Comment: bro vedas in every god hymn praises him there no ultimate god like tridevas in vedas.

Comment: Brahman, or more precisely Brahm (not BrahmA) or Parbrahm . it refers to the supreme deity , the god of gods, known in various religions as god, allah, yahweh , bhagwan , waheguru , etc

Comment: @Elfinforest Brahman is used to refer Supreme God Brahman. Actually Brahmaa (creator god) is often written as Brahma (as writing extra a in Brahmaa is often avoided). So to remove confusion we write Brahman (also as per sanskrit too, Brahman is root word, so it is not a mind woven convention to write Brahma(supreme) as Brahman).

Answer (score 3):

Agni is central in  all vedic rituals. All the offerings in the Vedic sacrifices are invariably offered to Agni and through him to other gods. Agni is thus the primary recipient of all Vedic sacrifices.So he is also  Divine messenger of the gods. You can read more about Agni in this [**Answer**](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16585/what-is-the-significance-of-fire-in-rituals).

---

The Rigveda itself indicates that Truth is one - "ekam sad vipra bahudha vadanti agnim yamam matariswanam ahuh" (meaning Truth is one, but the learned refer to it in different names like agni, yama, Varuna , Vayu etc. But the concept that there is a single Parabrahman and that all Gods are Its forms, is more clearly visible towards the Vedanta (Upanishads).

> इन्द्रं मित्रं वरुणमग्निमाहुरथो दिव्यः स सुपर्णो गरुत्मान | 
>   एकं सद विप्रा बहुधा वदन्त्यग्निं यमं मातरिश्वानमाहुः ||[**RV 1.164.46**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01164.htm) ||
>
> 46  They call him Indra, Mitra, Varuṇa, Agni, and he is heavenly
>   nobly-winged Garutmān. To **what is One**, sages give many a title
>   they call it Agni, Yama, Mātariśvan.

---

The  core concepts of Upanishads is  Brahman-Atman.  Brahman is the material, efficient, formal and final cause of all that exists.  Brahman is "the infinite"  source, fabric, core and destiny of all existence, both manifested and unmanifested.

Now let's look at the mantras of Kena- Upanishad and Shankara’s Commentary on the **"Yakshopakhyan"** part which you mentioned in question.

> The [**Brahman**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/kena-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc145054.html)  won a victory for the Devas and in that victory of the
>   Brahman the Devas attained glory. They thought ‘the victory is ours
>   and this glory is ours alone.’
>
> The[**Brahman**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/kena-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc145055.html)  evidently knew this false notion of theirs. Brahman being
>   omniscient and director of the senses of all living beings knew of the
>   false idea of the Devas and in order that the Devas might not be
>   disgraced like the Asuras by this false notion, out of pity for them
>   and intending to bless them hy dispelling their false notion, appeared
>   before them.

So from the above lets try to construct answers of your two questions.

## Is agni-and-vayu-great-because-rigveda-eulogized-them ?

Yes they are great gods of vedic as well as current time , and both as well as others will be greatly reveared in the rest of the coming time as well. But they are not just great because only Rig-Veda says so. The Vedic people also realised the importance of Agni not only for  earth but for entire universe including bodies of living beings. So Agni and vayu are great in Rig-Veda because they are part of infinite Brahman. And that is the reason why the deities sometimes are called as Brahman and they are also Blessing people , supporting life on earth , and bringing prosperity to all.

## or are they not great because they're subject to ego in Kenopanishad?

As described above the Brahman just taking pity on gods and just for preventing them turning like Asuras , tried to to bless them hy dispelling their false notion. And appeared before them just to show them this fact that " He is the Director of the Show" . This does not anyhow lowers their importance in Vedic  or later litraturre. They did not express their ego anywhere But they were under false notion (Avidya /ignorance)  Since they are the devas who are just extension of Brahman itself , they still are great.

---

**conclusion** - According to me none of your statements are right in the sense of either vedas or vedanta. They are just general interpretations  drawn at Vyavaharika level.

Comment: so deities dont exist as at absolute level ?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi they don't

Comment: @Sikhandyeshallfind i.e as per sankara vedanta but vedas dont mention such things

Comment: @RakeshJoshi, as per upanishads, all deities are creation of Parbrahm , and hence in the absolute, all these deities don't exist.

न तत्र सूर्यो भाति न चन्द्रतारकं नेमा विद्युतो भान्ति कुतोऽयमग्निः । 
तमेव भान्तमनुभाति सर्वं तस्य भासा सर्वमिदं विभाति ॥ १५ ॥

15. The sun does not shine there; nor do the moon and the stars, nor do these lightnings shine. How could this FIRE? Him shining, all shine after. All this shines by his light.
(Kathopanisad)

Comment: @Sikhandyeshallfind There is no vyavaharika or paramartha levels in Upanishad. If so show me. But in chat room. Cos this is not place for extended comments.

Comment: I don't understand what is 'vyavaharika' or 'paramartha' level ?
vyavaharik as name suggest is 'practical' right ? parmarath is ultimate goal . so whats the issue ?
please refer above updated comment :)